# Laravel - Hash::check() return always false

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Hello I'm using Laravel 4 and I want to check if a  user's password exists in the database, so I do this :

```
 Return Hash::check($password, Auth::user()->password);
```

The problem I get always `false` even `$password` value is correct

Comment: Works fine for me. Could you paste some more code?

Answer (score 3):

You have used this:

```
Return Hash::check($password, Auth::user()->password);
```

It always returns false because `Auth::user()->password);` will be available only when the user is logged in and I'm assuming that, you are checking the password when the user is not logged in.

Comment: Heh, I didn't even think of that assumption. But I'd wager you're right.

Comment: @JoelHinz, Thanks! I'm assuming this because `OP` mentioned `The problem I get always false even $password value is correct`, so what else can you think ?

Comment: My first thoughts were that OP is logged in with another user, or that the ``$password`` hasn't been correctly set after all. But I think Occam prefers your solution. :)